# Ссылка с js проверкой

Tags: javascript, html

Имею на сайте в навигации вкладки, контент по ним расположен на index.html

```
<a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" onClick="if(location)" href="#home-md" role="tab" aria-controls="home-md"
  aria-selected="true">Home</a>
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab-md">
<p>Это главная страница</p></div>
```

На сайте имеются другие страницы, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне с другой страницы перейти на index.html и на нужный якорь. Что то пробовал js типо `href="javascript:myFun(#home-md);"` в функции проверяет если я не на index.html, то перейти и открыть нужный контент, а если на ней то просто перейти по якорю. Так и не выйшло, частично работает..., с якорями не понял. Не силен прост, возможностей всех не знаю. Заранее спасибо друзья.

```
<a href="javascript:myFun('#home-md2');">запуск функции</a> 
<script> function myFun(n) { 
if(location.pathname != "/" + "index" + "." + "html"){ 
document.location.href = "/321/index.html" + n; 
} 
}
```

[spravki54.ru/321/index.html](http://spravki54.ru/321/index.html) и 
[spravki54.ru/321/price.html](http://spravki54.ru/321/price.html)

это тестовые странички с price переходит на index и подставляет хеш, в вот с index не получается

Или второй вариант как хотелось бы сделать сайт, это не вкладками, а как лендинг и по навигации проматывался, есть рабочий пример, плавно проматывает, однако в нем та же проблема, как перейти с другой страницы и по нужному якорю мотать. Думаю рабочий скрипт подойдет мне и туда и туда, уж выберу потом как мне сделать сайт.

Comment: Покажите функцию `myFun`.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1116234/edit). Добавьте код в вопрос, пожалуйста.